# add custom object by modifying the object by matching the json object using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation, mongoose

```js
const data = [
  {
    system: {
      id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
      mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
      singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
      shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
      multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
      shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
      india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
      locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
    },
  },
];
  result = data.reduce(
    (
      r,
      {
        system: {
          id,
          content: {
            type: { name },
          },
        },
        DataDetails,
      }
    ) => {
      r[name] ??= {};
      Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
          r[name][loc] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id][key] = value; 
        });
      });
      return r;
    },
    {}
  );

console.log(result)
```

my this is my object

### fields

```
{
  "Author": { "fields": "shortSlugOption" },
  "testing": { "fields": "mediaaccess" },
  "dummy": { "fields": "fieldtest" },
  "new": { "fields": "fieldtest" },
}
```

I am trying to check and assign the value which is present inside the fields object with the key which is present in side result obj and assign the value

so in the fields object

```
"new": { "fields": "oneReference" }
```

I want to check the oneReference present in `new`

```
  "new": {
    "hi": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "oneReference": "values 1",
        "media": {
          "conf": {
            "type": "media",
            "id": "01"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "multiReference": "values 2"
      }
    },
    "hi-IN": {
      "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE": {
        "testingNewValue": "jksdsdo"
      }
    }
  },
```

so here my expected output is like this

### Expected Output

```
  "new": {
    "hi": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "subject": "values 1"
        "id": "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
        "address": "/new/values 1"
        "oneReference": "values 1",
        "media": {
          "conf": {
            "type": "media",
            "id": "01"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "subject": "values 1"
        "id": "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
        "address": "/new/values 1"
        "multiReference": "values 2"
      }
    },
    "hi-IN": {
      "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE": {
        "subject": "unknown"
        "id": "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
        "address": "/new/unknown"
        "testingNewValue": "jksdsdo"
      }
    }
  },
```

here we can see  `new:hi` and `new:hi-In` contain same id `66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW` so its should check field object `oneReference` present in which id and assign that value in `subject` but in the `new:hi-IN` the id `cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE` does not contain `oneReference` then it should print `unknown` like this I want to check for `Author testing dummy` and many more if they are present in the `fields` object and check the value present or not in the `result` and display Unknown if the value is not present but display the actual key value

so I tried this but no help

```js
let field = {
  Author: { fields: "shortSlugOption" },
  testing: { fields: "mediaaccess" },
  dummy: { fields: "fieldtest" },
  new: { fields: "fieldtest" },
};

const data = [
  {
    system: {
      id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
      mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
      singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
      shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
      multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
      shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
      india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
      locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
    },
  },
];

Object.keys(field).map((type) => {
  const searchKey = field[type]?.fields;

  result = data.reduce(
    (
      r,
      {
        system: {
          id,
          content: {
            type: { name },
          },
        },
        DataDetails,
      }
    ) => {
      r[name] ??= {};
      Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
          r[name][loc] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id] ??= {subject:"hello", id:id, address:`${name}/hello`};
          r[name][loc][id][key] = value;
          
        });
      });
      console.log(r);
      return r;
    },
    {}
  );
  
  const typeObject = result[type] ?? {};
  let subject;
  outer: for (key in typeObject) {
    const value = typeObject[key];
    subject = null;
    for (subkey in value) {
      const subvalue = value[subkey];
      subject = subvalue[searchKey];
      if (subject != null) break;
    }
    console.log(subject ?? "Unknown");
  }
});
```

In place of `hello` I am trying to get the value of `shortSlugOption` and other values which are present inside the `field` Object but if the `shortSlugOption` present in `en-us za-op or hi` then it should take first value from this key if the `shortSlugOption` is not present inside `en-us` then it should check `za-op` and assign that value but if in `en-us and za-op` the value is not present then it should check the other `hi` like this but as we can see `Author en-us 1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5`  does not contain `shortSlugOption` then it should print `unknown` in place of `hello`

Comment: The main obstacle is inserting `this.firstName`. You can try writing a function that returns the `{ validator: ..., message: ... }` object and accepts a key argument like `"firstName"`, then uses `this[key]` in the inner function. Moving that to a separate module is a different question.

Comment: can you simplify your question?

Comment: @Aakash please check the answer if it met your specified requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It seem unnecessary to run [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) again and again if we want to use the same result at the end.

Created a structure that can used in second loop to create our final result

```js
let field = {
  Author: { fields: "shortSlugOption" },
  testing: { fields: "mediaaccess" },
  dummy: { fields: "fieldtest" },
  new: { fields: "fieldtest" },
};

const data = [
  {
    system: {
      id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
      mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
      singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
      shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
      multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
      shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
      india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
      locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
    },
  },
];

let result = data.reduce((r, {
      system: {
        id,
        content: {
          type: { name },
        },
      },
      DataDetails,
    }
  ) => {
    r[name] ??= {};
    r["$$TMP$$"][id] ??= { shortSlugOption: {}, oneReference: { values: [] } }
    Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
      Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
        r[name][loc] ??= {};
        r[name][loc][id] ??= {subject: "hello", id: id, address:`${name}/`};
        r[name][loc][id][key] = value;
        
        if (key == 'oneReference') {
          r["$$TMP$$"][id][key][loc] = value;
          r["$$TMP$$"][id][key]['values'].push(value);
        }
        else if (key == 'shortSlugOption') {
          r["$$TMP$$"][id][key][loc] = value;
        }
      });
    });
    return r;
  }, { "$$TMP$$": {} }
);

Object.keys(field).map((type) => {
  const searchKey = field[type]?.fields;

  const typeObject = result[type] ?? {};
  outer: for (key in typeObject) {
    const value = typeObject[key];
    // let subject = null;
    for (subkey in value) {
      const subvalue = value[subkey];
      // subject = subvalue[searchKey];

      subvalue["subject"] = result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['oneReference'][key] ?? result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['oneReference']['values'].length > 0 ? result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['oneReference']['values'][0] : "Unknown";
      if (result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['shortSlugOption']['en-us']) {
        subvalue["address"] += result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['shortSlugOption']['en-us']
      }
      else if (result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['shortSlugOption']['za-op']) {
        subvalue["address"] += result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['shortSlugOption']['za-op']
      }
      else if (result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['shortSlugOption']['hi']) {
        subvalue["address"] += result["$$TMP$$"][subkey]['shortSlugOption']['hi']
      }
      else {
        subvalue["address"] += 'hello';
      }
      // if (subject != null) break;
    }
  }
});

delete result['$$TMP$$'];

console.log(result);
```

---

Refactored version with only [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let field = {
  Author: { fields: "shortSlugOption" },
  testing: { fields: "mediaaccess" },
  dummy: { fields: "fieldtest" },
  new: { fields: "fieldtest" },
};

const data = [
  {
    system: {
      id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
      mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
      singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
      shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
      multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
      shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
      india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
      locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
    },
  },
];

let result = data.reduce((r, {
      system: {
        id,
        content: {
          type: { name },
        },
      },
      DataDetails,
    }
  ) => {
    r[name] ??= {};
    Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
      Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
        r[name][loc] ??= {};
        r[name][loc][id] ??= {
          subject: "hello",
          id: id,
        };
        r[name][loc][id][key] = value;
        // console.log(r[name][loc][id]);
        let keys = Object.keys(DataDetails['oneReference'] || []);
        r[name][loc][id]['subject'] = DataDetails['oneReference'] && DataDetails['oneReference'][loc] ? DataDetails['oneReference'][loc] : keys.length > 0 ? DataDetails['oneReference'][keys[0]] : "Unknown";
        
        let address = DataDetails['shortSlugOption'] && DataDetails['shortSlugOption']['en-us'] ? DataDetails['shortSlugOption']['en-us'] : "";
        address = address == '' && DataDetails['shortSlugOption'] && DataDetails['shortSlugOption']['za-op'] ? DataDetails['shortSlugOption']['za-op'] : "";        
        address = address == '' && DataDetails['shortSlugOption'] && DataDetails['shortSlugOption']['hi'] ? DataDetails['shortSlugOption']['hi'] : "";
        r[name][loc][id]['address'] ??= `${name}/` + (address == '' ? 'hello' : address);
      });
    });
    return r;
  }, {}
);

console.log(result);
```